# Page Contents Fades Out After 1 Second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-backstretch

I have an website that a modal. Whenever I visit one page, however, only on a mobile device, all the content fades off the screen after 1 second of being there. I am using `backstretch.js`, and this exact HTML: `<div class="modalDialog"><div></div></div>` is required to be on the page, in order for the content to stay.  My CSS for the `.modalDialog` class looks like this:

```
.modalDialog {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Is there anything in this CSS that would be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: We'll likely need to see some additional code, your modal has an opacity of 0 but I wouldn't expect that alone to be an issue (unless the rest of your content is in the modal)

Comment: Inspect the element in the browser and see what happens. Do you know what code is running at that time? If it is an issue with your plugin, you might consider using an alternative to the plugin.